# Angular js email form Validation

Tags: angularjs

I came across this plunk while searching for email validation in angular js ... http://plnkr.co/edit/L0mbRw?p=preview . Now the email validation used here works the way I want it but when I copied the code and created a new plunk here ... http://plnkr.co/edit/hbo0GcRx9F7t2CkjBS3n?p=preview the validation stops working. I check everything was same but it isn't working the same way.

Comment: It works for me, what exactly isn't working for you?

Comment: actually doesn't work correctly.  this validates: xxx@xxx

Answer (score 0):

Its working Fine, even when i create a JSFiddle with that also its working fine,

Take a look at this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/64/)**

[image]

**html**

```
<body ng-app='validationApp'  ng-controller='mainController'>
    <form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate="">
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine }">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" />
          <p ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
```

**script**

```
var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', []);

validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
});
```